# How to interpret a seasonal ARIMA model?

Tags: arima, model, interpretation

I have an auto.arima model output with ARIMA(000)(110)[4] with sigma^2=0.005, so I assume the model fits well the data. But I'm trying to understand the model itself... 
If I did all the maths correctly, the change at time *t* depends on the change at the same time in 2 previous years, being expressed as:

x<sub>t</sub> = (α<sub>1</sub>+1) x<sub>t-4</sub> - α<sub>1</sub>x<sub>t-8</sub> + wt.

Is it correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's right.  Assuming you don't have a constant in the model, and using your notation, then the model with one seasonal difference and one seasonal AR term is

$(1 - \alpha_1 L^4)(1 - L^4)x_t = \epsilon_t$

which is

$x_t - \alpha_1 x_{t-4} - x_{t-4} + \alpha_1 x_{t-8} = \epsilon_t$

or, as you wrote,

$x_t = (1 + \alpha_1)x_{t-4} - \alpha_1 x_{t-8} + \epsilon_t$